# React JS Filter issue if object has "null" value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filtering

I have a list of documents that can return null value from the db. Namely documentAuthor and featureId.

The user can filter the list by clicking on the heading section of each column. Namely documentAuthor or featureID etc.

If the properties are null I want them to still be visible within the UI. The filtering I've done below is preventing that from happening for some reason - if I comment out filtering logic for documentAuthor and featureId the correct amount of records show.

How can I resolve this filtering issue? The "?" on documentAuthor and featureId is to check it's either going to be populated or null.

My filtering:

```
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState({
    documentAuthor: '',
    documentName: '',
    documentSource: '',
    documentType: 'All',
    documentUploadDateFrom: '',
    documentUploadDateTo: new Date().toISOString(),
    featureId: '',
    fileFormat: '',
  });





 useEffect(() => {
    setDocuments(claimsStore.getIncomingDocuments());

    const filteredDocuments = documents.filter(
      (document) =>
        document.documentAuthor?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentAuthor.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentName?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentName.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentSource?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentSource.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.documentType.includes(filters.documentType === 'All' ? '' : filters.documentType) &&
        document.featureId?.includes(filters.featureId) &&
        document.mimeType.toLowerCase().includes(filters.fileFormat.toLowerCase()) &&
        document.uploadDateTime > filters.documentUploadDateFrom &&
        document.uploadDateTime < filters.documentUploadDateTo,
    );
    
    setRows(
      filteredDocuments.map((document) =>
        createData(
          document.documentAuthor ?? '',
          document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
          document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
          document.documentName ?? '',
          document.documentSource ?? '',
          document.documentType,
          document.featureId ?? '',
          document.mimeType,
          document.uploadDateTime,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }, [claimsStore, documents, filters]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using optional chaining, with a nullish object, subsequent property accesses are not evaluated, cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#short-circuiting.

When documentAuthor or featureId properties are null, the whole expression returns undefined, which is falsy, and so the document is filtered out of the collection. You need to allow null values explicitly like this:

```js
const filteredDocuments = documents.filter(
      (document) =>
          // !document.documentAuthor is a shortcut to document.documentAuthor == null
          (!document.documentAuthor || document.documentAuthor.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentAuthor.toLowerCase())) &&
          document.documentName?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentName.toLowerCase()) &&
          document.documentSource?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentSource.toLowerCase()) &&
          document.documentType.includes(filters.documentType === 'All' ? '' : filters.documentType) &&
          (!document.featureId || document.featureId.includes(filters.featureId) &&
          document.mimeType.toLowerCase().includes(filters.fileFormat.toLowerCase()) &&
          document.uploadDateTime > filters.documentUploadDateFrom &&
          document.uploadDateTime < filters.documentUploadDateTo,
    );
    
setRows(
    filteredDocuments.map((document) =>
        createData(
            document.documentAuthor ?? '',
            document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
            document.documentMetadataId.toLocaleString(),
            document.documentName ?? '',
            document.documentSource ?? '',
            document.documentType,
            document.featureId ?? '',
            document.mimeType,
            document.uploadDateTime,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mathieu! This is great and thank you for the explanation on the chaining with the nullish obj. I'm getting an eslint error for Unnecessary option chain on a non-nullish value?

Comment: I think I fixed it removing the ? checking for null as we are already doing that in the first instance - thank you!

Comment: Yes, you don't need it anymore as `document.documentAuthor?.toLowerCase().includes(filters.documentAuthor.toLowerCase())` won't be evaluated if `document.documentAuthor` is null (javascript shortcutting again)

Comment: If you can update your code please I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Hey, just a note - I've lost the ability to actually use the filters with this logic in place. I have a table which renders these results and in the heading there is an input for the user to filter by featureID which are numbers and so on for other categories. Through thorough testing it's because of the null check - is there a way around this to render null objects AND be retain filtering functionality?